# Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Int -> Char' with actual type `Char'

Tags: haskell

I have the following haskell code. The piece thats commented out runs well, but i wanted to make it a bit shorter by using lambdas. Unfortunately i dont seem to compile the code. 
intToDigit returns a Character but for values below 15. Thats what i suspected was causing the problem..

```
printSudRow :: [Maybe Int] -> String
printSudRow []       = []
--printSudRow (ro:ros) = parseMaybeToStr ro : printSudRow ros
--                       where parseMaybeToStr Nothing  = '.'
--                           parseMaybeToStr (Just v) = intToDigit v
printSudRow (ro:ros) = (\ro -> 
    if (isJust ro) then intToDigit $ fromJust ro else '.') : printSudRow ros
```

Comment: Sorry for my untested, obviously wrong, and now deleted answer. I should perhaps refrain from answering questions while engaged with other activities.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use `fromJust` when you can do pattern matching. Usage of partial functions should be kept to a strict minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for what you want to do here you don't need the lambda at all (that is causing the problem):

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

printSudRow :: [Maybe Int] -> String
printSudRow []       = []
printSudRow (ro:ros) = (if (isJust ro) then intToDigit $ fromJust ro else '.') : printSudRow ros
```

of course when you already use pattern matching why don't you go all the way:

```
printSudRow :: [Maybe Int] -> String
printSudRow []       = []
printSudRow (Just ro:ros) = intToDigit ro : printSudRow ros
printSudRow (Nothing:ros) = '.' : printSudRow ros
```

this way you don't need the `fromJust`, `isJust` and the ugly `if` at all!

and with `maybe` (which duplode already mentioned) and `map` you can get a oneliner as well:

```
printSudRow :: [Maybe Int] -> String
printSudRow = map (maybe '.' intToDigit)
```